# iterating through memory to reading values

Tags: c++, memory, input, io

I have the current code that readings a text file into memory:

```
std::streampos fsize = 0;
std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary); // open file

if(!file.good()) {
    std::cout << "Error opening file";
    return 0;
}

// get length of file
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
fsize = file.tellg();

// allocate memory
char *memory = new char[fsize];

// read data as a block
file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
file.read (memory, fsize);

file.close(); // close file

return fsize;
```

Now i have code that iterates over it. If the line starts with 'v'  it reads the 3 preceding float values, and same with if it starts with 'n', but into different arrays.

```
char* p = memory;       // pointer to start of memory
char* e = memory + fsize;   // pointer to end of memory

while (p != e) {
    if (memcmp(p, "v", 1) == 0) { 
        sscanf(p, "v %f %f %f", &a[vI], &b[vI], &c[vI]);
        vI++;
    } else if (memcmp(p, "n",  1) == 0) {
        sscanf(p, "v %f %f %f", &d[nI], &e[nI], &f[nI]);
        nI++;           
    while (*p++ != (char) 0x0A);
}
```

I know there must be a better/safer way to do this.

Comment: You open the file in binary mode, but it appears to be a text-file. Is that intentional?

Comment: hmm, would std::ios::in be more suited?

Comment: If you have a text-file, you don't need to specify anything, the default will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a text-file there. This can be done a lot simpler. First, don't open the file in binary-mode, and simply read linewise. The following is a possible implementation:

```
template<class output_iterator>
void read_file(std::istream &input, output_iterator v1, output_iterator v2,
               output_iterator v1) {
    std::string line_buffer;

    while(std::getline(input, line_buffer)) { // read each line of text
        if(line_buffer[0] == 'v') {
            std::stringstream line_stream(line_buffer.substr(1)); // drop the 'v'
            // read three consecutive floats
            line_stream >> *v1++ >> *v2++ >> *v3++; 
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes that lines starting with `'v'` are well-formed. You can use it like this:

```
std::vector<float> values1, values2, values3;
std::fstream input_file(fileName);

read_file(input_file, std::back_inserter(values1), std::back_inserter(values2),
          std::back_inserter(values3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) if your system supports it (i.e. any *nix-like system). This will (very quickly) give you a `char*` to the file contents. If your file is big, this works great as it uses the virtual memory system to cache everything for you - i.e you don't have to wait while all the data is copied around. The mmap function returns instantly and the relevant section of virtual memory is already mapped to the your file.

```
int fd = open(binaryRAWFileName, O_RDONLY);
... should do some error check to ensure fd != -1

// get the size of the file
struct stat sb;
if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) {
        ... there was an error with fstat
}

char * memory = mmap(NULL  // we don't care where the memory is
        , sb.st_size      // length of the file
        , PROT_READ   
        , MAP_PRIVATE
        , fd            // the file descriptor of course
        , 0);
```

Finally, `memcmp` seems a bit pointless with a length of 1. Why not just to `if(*p=='v')` instead of `if(memcmp(p, "v", 1) == 0)`